# How to remove the UIImageView From the custom UIView

Tags: ios, uiview, uiimageview

i create the the imageView by programatically and add that imageView to the Custom UIView.then i by click the button i want to add another imageView to the same custom UIView,here the old and new imageView also displaying,so i need to remove the first added imageView then i add the new imageView. help me to remove the imageView..

```
    CGRect rect=CGRectMake(10, 10, 100,100);
    UIImageView *imageView=[[UIImageView alloc]init];
    imageView.frame=rect;
    imageView.backgroundColor=[UIColor redColor];
    [self.customView addSubview:imageView];//add the imageView to UIView
```

Answer (score 2):

When you add the first imageView set its tag like

```
imageView.tag = 232;
```

Later you can ask your customView for this imageView and remove it.

Call this function.

```
[[customView viewWithTag:232] removeFromSuperview];
```

Comment: i already tried it not working,now i update my question in detail,help me

Comment: Which frame of custom view you set? You should redraw view after remove imgView. Try this: `[customView setNeedsDisplay];`

Answer (score 1):

Use this code.

```
[[self.customView viewWithTag:1000] removeFromSuperView]
CGRect rect=CGRectMake(10, 10, 100,100);
UIImageView *imageView=[[UIImageView alloc]init];
[imageView setTag:1000];
imageView.frame=rect;
imageView.backgroundColor=[UIColor redColor];
[self.customView addSubview:imageView];
```